# jsPDF - multiple pages - rendering HTML always going to page1

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

We use jsPDF 2.5.1 to render a multi page PDF.

We use the html function to render various DOM elements to each page, and this was working in version 1.x of jsPDF

However now every time we call .html() - it puts it on the first page, rather than the newly added page, here is the code

```
if (pdfPageIndex < numPdfPages) {
    if (pdfPageIndex > 0) {
        pdf.addPage();
    }

    pdf.html(
        document.getElementById('pdfPage_' + pdfPageIndex),             
        {
         html2canvas: {
             logging: true
             },
         callback: function(){ return pdfCallback($scope)}});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please try with below addImage method based on canvas height and width it will render in multiple pages

```
const data = document.getElementById('pdfPage_');
html2canvas(data).then((canvas:any) => {
  const imgWidth = 208;
  const pageHeight = 295;
  const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
  let heightLeft = imgHeight;
  let position = 0;
  heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  const doc = new jspdf('p', 'mm');
  doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
  while (heightLeft >= 0) {
    position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
    doc.addPage();
    doc.addImage(canvas, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight, '', 'FAST');
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  }
  doc.save('Downld.pdf');
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thats what I ended up doing.