# long table getting cut off in a generated PDF when using the html2canvas and jsPDF libraries in a ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using the html2canvas and jsPDF libraries in a ReactJS component to export a table to a PDF file. However, I encounter an issue where the table is too long to fit within a single page, causing it to be cut off and not fully visible in the generated PDF.

I want to split the table into multiple pages if the size is too long.

Function that handles exporting.

```
    const pdfRef = useRef()
    
      const exportPDF = () => {
        const input = pdfRef.current;
        html2canvas(input).then((canvas) => {
          const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
          const pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4', true);
          const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
          const pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
          const imgWidth = canvas.width;
          const imgHeight = canvas.height;
          const ratio = Math.min(pdfWidth / imgWidth, pdfHeight / imgHeight);
          const imgX = (pdfWidth - imgWidth * ratio) / 2;
          const imgY = 0;
          pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', imgX, imgY, imgWidth * ratio, imgHeight * ratio);
          pdf.save('peerss-employees.pdf')
        })
      }
```

The PDF I received was cut off by the 8th row, but it actually has 23 rows:

[image]

Comment: You need to loop through the original image created by the canvas and add a page to the pdf for each "portion" of the image. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72368607/jspdf-multiple-pages-rendering-html-always-going-to-page1 for an example . However as the image has no context of the table row, you might have the table cut off in the middle of the row. If this is not acceptable, you will need another (harder) solution